# How do I know what side of my TouchableOpacity was pressed?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I'd like to run different logic based on if the left or right side of my TouchableOpacity is pressed.

I plan to use the locationX property of event.nativeEvent to know the spot that was touched. But I'm not sure where to get the current width of the TouchableOpacity to do the math.

```
onPress={(event) => {
              if (event.nativeEvent.locationX >= (the_width / 2)
                    //right side or exact center was pressed
              else
                    //left side was pressed
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do. u get when u console.log event.nativeEvent.locationX ?

Comment: It gives me a number corresponding to the X coordinate where I touched. I think the value goes up to 480 since it's taking up the full width.

Comment: check my answer @Ellery

Answer (score 0):

First add reference to your component

```
myref = useRef();

<TouchableOpacity
ref = {myref}
>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now when component is loaded measure the component using useeffect

```
useEffect(()=>{


myref.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
            console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
            console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
            console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
            console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
            console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
        })        


},[])
```

Now save this values in states and u can do some calculations on press.

Comment: No luck, i'm getting an "undefined is not a function" for the call the to measure